# Instant Alert notification feature using PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Need to display incoming mails when the user is currently logged in. Can we use socket server programming concept for this requirement. Need help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/

Avoid using PHP's native socket support. They're an absolute mess, you will end up tearing your eyeballs out.

Or you could just poll an ajax script every couple of seconds.

Comment: I have already used ajax but it takes long timeouts, causes network intensive, etc.... I thought phpwebsocket ll help me in this issue. but can you explain me in detail why do you dont prefer it.

Comment: Optimize your mail check script so it returns minimal information. If there's no mail, return a  `0`. If there's mail, encode as json object and gzip it.

Comment: I have created the notification feature for my mail using jQuery and Ajax. But need some help regarding close button in notice. Got to update my notify database if the user clicks the close button, so that the notification is not queried again by the script.